# Integrate Magento with Amazon

Tags: magento-1.8, amazon

I am sure if I am allowed to ask advices here.
I need to integrate Amazon with Magento. I need a module which can handle configurable products. This [Amazon extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/amazon-1.html) seems to support only configurable from some categories and doesn't match with my category. Also I want to get billing and shipping addresses as well. 
Did you integrate Amazon with a module without limitations like these?

Comment: @Serpyre: I would like more one time fee. Thanks

Comment: @Serpyre: I am not sure I understood you. Is there any good solution with one time fee? I am a developer but I don't have time to build it because I need it quick and perfect :)

Comment: @Serpyre: from what I read there are issues. What I really need is same functionality as Amazon extension but to work with configurable as well, to not be limited to a category or a specific attribute. I don't need something special. If you have some solution, please give me more details and I will discuss them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use M2E pro
Now its supporting configurable products
And it's free

http://m2epro.com

Comment: How can I test the module on a development server? Is it fine to use live credentials for tests?

Comment: Yes no problem with that. Anyway you have the sandbox option

Comment: Hmm.. I followed video tutorials but in the 3rd step 
Adding your Amazon accounts to M2E Pro extension. when I am redirected, I get 
    Insufficient user rights.

You have insufficient rights to continue with registration. Please contact the primary Seller Central account owner to verify your permissions.

Comment: This is you need to verify your Amazon account. You need to follow the amazon verification process.

This may help you
https://payments.amazon.com/help/81716

Comment: Yeah..I don't get nothing. Is the account related to the one from M2E account? I used my own email for that one. Should I use an account with the email for Amazon? I am confused

Comment: It's free for first year only I believe.

Answer (score 3):

Is there any reason why the main Magento extension for Amazon and eBay won't work for you from M2E Pro?

Below gives full details:

http://m2epro.com/amazon/

Download from here:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/ebay-magento-integration-order-import-and-stock-level-synchronization-also-supports-amazon-rakuten-and-play-com.html

To my knowledge, configurable products work fine with this extension, although never tested, only with simple products. But looking at the release notes on the above link, it should work fine. Hope this answer helps?

Comment: As I read in comments in reviews I understood that : Fully supported with eBay, no support in Amazon ( it reads Variable products and lists the children as simple products only ). I can't speak as to the other channels.
and also 
M2Epro does not support import of billing address if it is different from delivery address.

Comment: Hi Denisa, I've not used the extension in over 3 months as we no longer retail on eBay or Amazon, but I do know it can definitely support the import of shipping and billing address being different. And it can definitely support configurable products. This extension is the biggest and best free extension for importing/export into and out of Ebay and Amazon. Takes a while to configure everything in your Magento admin, but easy and quick to use on daily basis, all ran with cron task for full automation :)

Comment: So, you are saying that should be perfect for me. My concerns were related to those 2 aspects. Thanks

Comment: I can't see any issues at all. If you have any concerns before downloading and putting live, email their support, they'll likely get back to you within 1 working day at most. They have a giant forum too and big FAQ area! Enjoy.

Comment: Thank you! I will give it a try next week. The guys from Boost My Shop - Amazon extension didn't even bother to answer to my emails/questions.

Answer (score 1):

There are really only two extensions for this in late 2016, and neither are free any longer.

1. The one I have experience with (and used to be free via partnership with eBay) is [M2E Pro](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/ebay-amazon-rakuten-magento-integration-order-import-and-stock-level-synchronization.html). The partnership with eBay has ended, and the module is technically free to install, but won't function without a valid subscription, which is rather expensive if you have any kind of volume with Amazon. A business doing $60k/month of revenue should expect about $200/month for a subscription. It also appears from my testing back when the service was free that significant portions, if not all off the connections to Amazon, is routed through M2E's servers. Several times in the past few years we had multi-hour outages where the software simply wasn't syncing, and eventually M2E fessed up that it was something on their end. So M2E knows everything about your business, what you sell, your customer informative, etc...

   You can also *never* uninstall the plugin, as it has so many deep hooks into magento (that admitidly add neat things, like deep-linking directly to the Amazon order page for a specific order, pulling shipping details for FBA shippments ,etc). Uninstalling the plugin renders your site non-functional, and the plugin bitches constantly if you have it installed without a valid subscription.
2. The other option, is [this](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/fulfillment-by-amazon.html) module from Webtex1. I have no experience with this plugin, but it seems on paper to be the better option (same basic feature set, one time purchase).

Answer (score 0):

Please check Amazon Products Manager Magento Extension. It supports import configurable products from Amazon to Magento. 
https://web-experiment.info/magento-amazon-products-manager
It use Amazon Advertising API to import products from Amazon to Magento.